# Gradle: using other (unofficial) tasks inside custom task class?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

Say I want to write a custom Gradle task in `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/JDKDownloader.groovy` which can download any version of the Java JDK. It looks something like this:

```
class JDKDownloader extends DefaultTask {
    String version = getLatestJDKVersion()
    String dest = null;

    @TaskAction
    def download() {
        .. code to download JDK ..
    }

    private String getLatestJDKVersion() {
        .. code to find latest JDK version ..
    }
}
```

One can use it like this:

```
task downloadJDK16(type: JDKDownloader) {
    version = '1.6'
    dest = 'jdkDownload'
}
```

Now, the question is: for this concrete example I want to use the Gradle download plugin [here](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task), since it shows a nice progress display when downloading files. But how do I use this plugin/task in a propery way inside JDKDownloader? In a normal Gradle script one has to do this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:0.5'
    }
}
```

After which one can use it like this:

```
download {
    src: 'someurl'
    dest: 'somedir'
}
```

But, how do we do this from `JDKDownloader`? Obviously it's not a pretty solution to require the user of the class to apply the download plugin himself, before he can use `JDKDownloader` (ugly implicit dependency). On the other hand it seems strange that `JDKDownloader` should mess with buildscript dependencies of the calling script.

So is there a nicer (propery) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you publish your plugin as a Maven or Ivy module, transitive dependency management will take care of its dependencies.

Comment: But, what if I just want to use the custom task class as a container to keep things clean, and not to build a plugin that's meant to be used in other modules? So instead of having all the JDK download functions inside my build.gradle I have put them into a JDKDownloader abstraction.

Comment: Then the download plugin becomes a regular compile or runtime dependency in `buildSrc/build.gradle`, and I think that's it.